# How to check if android device can send SMS, when hasSystemFeature is false?

Tags: android, android-sms

An app needs to know if it is capable of sending an SMS. Now what I can see is the following line is returning false for emulator.

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)
```

I am worried that if it is returning false with the emulator then it might be the case with real devices as well? 
Please confirm, if it is the right way to check SMS capabilities.

I cannot find any answer as such in SO, so I decided to create a new one.

How to reproduce?

I am using Nexus 5 emulator with API version 16.
 [image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem / not working?

Comment: "I am worried that if it is true in some devices as well" -- well, yes, it will be `true` for devices that have telephony capability. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your quick reply, I have just corrected my question

Comment: "I am worried that if it is returning false with the emulator then it might be the case with real devices as well?" -- well, sure. Not every device has telephony capability, such as WiFi-only tablets.

Comment: @CommonsWare It is about the mobile device that I am referring above. Question that I think coming  now - is it just because of emulator that I am getting false?

Comment: I think that you are taking the emulator descriptions too seriously. Your "Nexus 5 emulator" bears very little resemblance to a Nexus 5. Those AVD templates mimic screen size and density, but that is about it. So, other than for basic UI testing, it is pointless to consider that emulator as emulating a Nexus 5. The emulator returns `false` because it does not emulate complete telephony capability (e.g., it can emulate receiving SMS but not sending it).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for that. In that case what is the best way to test my app on a specific device, so that I can see and analyse user problem?

Comment: "In that case what is the best way to test my app on a specific device" -- buy the device. Or, find a hosted testing service that has that device. Or, borrow one from a friend.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it will return false Why?**

Because emulator don't have a Telephony feature But If you want to enable to go to emulator setting. But it will return true for Phones and false for Tablets or any device which don't have telephony feature will return false

### Better Way

```
if (((TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getPhoneType()
    == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
{
    // No calling feature available
}
```

Don't forget to add perm. to manifest `READ_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: @anaz aijaz - How can I change the same? Emulator does not have any such option.

Comment: Nope, just want to send SMS

Comment: Just one detail: many Android version don't have option to check if phone are single or dual SIM. On a dual SIM phone, when you try to send SMS using the SmsManager, you'll get an "OK" result when, in fact, nothing has been send.

Comment: what about emulator extended control > Phone > send message

Comment: May be emulator are designed to return false on check may be because they haven't proper hardware for telephony

Comment: Does this solved your problem? Do I am eligible for an upvote?